# Copy select netCDF dimension n times and all variables to new netCDF

Tags: python, python-3.x, netcdf, netcdf4, nco

I'm having trouble thinking of a way to copy a netCDF file n times on `dimension time`. The file contains 8 time dates [image] but I need to copy the 4th, 5th, 6th, and 7th values of `dimension time` 6 times along with each of the variables and the 8th once to a new netCDF file. What I'm hoping to create is `dimension time` of 25.

Any help with this irrational way of thinking would be appreciative.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The meaning of all the options is in the [manual](https://nco.sf.net/nco.html):

```
ncrcat -O -F -d time,4,7 in.nc out.nc
ncrcat --rec_apn -F -d time,4,7 in.nc out.nc
ncrcat --rec_apn -F -d time,4,7 in.nc out.nc
ncrcat --rec_apn -F -d time,4,7 in.nc out.nc
ncrcat --rec_apn -F -d time,4,7 in.nc out.nc
ncrcat --rec_apn -F -d time,4,8 in.nc out.nc
```

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried it but I think you can do this to get the answer in CDO.

Note that the order of the records will be 4,5,6,7,4,5,6,7 ... 8

You didn't specify in your question if you wanted that or 4,4,4,4,4,4,5,5, etc...

```
cdo seltimestep,4/7 in.nc out47.nc 
cdo seltimestep,8 in.nc out8.nc
cdo cat  out47.nc out47.nc out47.nc out47.nc out47.nc out47.nc out8.nc out.nc
```